# jquery scroll to content with mouse scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll

I would like the users scroll down the page block by block.
However, when the mouse scroll down, the page move non-stop til the end block.
My question is, how to move down only one block and stop until the next scroll?

Here is the code I tried.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    div{height:100%;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="statics/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        sectionSize = $( "div" ).length;

            idx = $( "div" ).index( $(".active") );

            if(idx+1 < sectionSize) {
                $("div").eq(idx).removeClass("active");
                $("div").eq(idx+1).addClass("active");


                $('html,body').animate( { scrollTop : $(".active").offset().top }, 'slow', function(){});

            }

    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="a active">a</div>
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
</body>
</html>
```